# How to write a regular expression that matches everything except secial characters

Tags: java

I have a very straigtfoward question. How would I write a regular expression that checks for anything that is not a special character.

I have something like this at the moment, but I need a way of saying "NOT THIS", because I'm trying to pull out data that is of varchar type, and varchar is alpha numeric which is pretty hard to validate because its letters and numbers, so i had the idea of basically saying anything but special characters:

`|\~|!|\@|#|\$|\%|\^|\&|*|(|)|+|\=|[|{|]|}|\||\|\'|\<|\,|.|>|\?|/|\""|\;|:|\s

Comment: Define "special character".

Comment: @shmosel well everything listed above, such as "@", "$", "£" and so on

Comment: I see your edit, but again what is a "special character?"  Do you mean control characters?  Non-ASCII?  Umlaut (those are pretty special to metal heads)?

Comment: If you want to exclude specific characters, you'll have to be specific. You're not going to find a regex that's tailor-made to your particular set of characters.

Comment: @markspace Hi, I meant characters such as "£", "$", "%", "&" so on

Comment: You can still simplify the regex though: `[^~!@#]` etc.

Comment: @shmosel I've listed the special characters I want to exclude in the OP

Comment: Conversely, if you want only ASCII alpha numeric characters, it's pretty easy to include them with something like`[A-Za-z0-9]*`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `/[a-z0-9]*/i`, this matches only alphanumeric characters - case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

[\w]* will match any "word" character 0 or more times, it will match any letter (uppercase or lowercase) digits and underscore (_), depending on if you find underscore special character you can do it differently, but I see there is no underscore in your "special characters" string.

Answer (score 0):

[a-zA-Z0-9] - this creates a simple set of all allowed characters in your case. You can simply check if given string contains anything that is not contained in this set. On the other hand, you may want to include in this set all the characters you do not allow in givem Strings.